# Optimize JQuery and Flex image slideshow

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, adobe, slideshow

I have a web page with an image slideshow.
JQuery calls a Flex app with a list of jpg images to load and display.
Can Flex load and display the first image and then continue loading the rest of the list,
or can Flex only do one thing at a time (ie. load all the images and then start the slideshow)?

There is a significant delay while all the images load and I need to sped up the slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the details provided by you, Flex app is doing the slide show.

Yes, application written in Flex can load images one by one and you can pause this loading, set priority etc at any time you want.

I suggest "BulkLoader" (https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader) to fully control your content that is loading dynamically.

Please find "BulkLoader" wiki pages (https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader/wiki) for more information about how to use this.

If you are using Flex app only for some simple photo slideshow with decent transitions, you can use jQuery's inbuilt effects slide, fade etc and create your own. You can find some good plugins available for photos slideshow.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: Flex callsback to JQuery after each image is loaded. After the last image is loaded Flex callsback and JQuery starts the slideshow.  Is it possible for JQuery to start the slideshow when Flex callsback after the first image is laoded?

Comment: I am still in confusion of how you are implementing this slideshow. But, yes, you communicate with jQuery to and from Flex at any time, using flash.external.ExternalInterface. jQuery can start slideshow at any time we want. More details with examples for ExternalInterface can be found at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html. Please let me know if you need further assistance in this. Sample code with your implementation will help us better to help you.